# How can I reset a form with jQuery chosen plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

I have a bunch of `select` elements in a form with which [I am using the Jquery Chosen plugin](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen). How can I reset the form? The following does not work:

```html
<input type="reset" />
```

Comment: You should change your accepted answer to Jack O'Neill's answer.  The other solutions do not work any more.

Comment: Please change your accepted ans to Jack O'Neill answere. because the latest version trigger now called :updated

Comment: @Jame & Well wisher: It's not like we will change all answered questions on this site whenever a plugin updates. The solution was correct at the time. RobertWaddell put a comment on the answer, I believe this is the way to go.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You'll need to reset the value of the field, then trigger the `liszt:updated` event on the input to get it to update, ive made a fiddle with a working example here.

http://jsfiddle.net/VSpa3/3/

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen();
$('a').click(function(){
    $(".chzn-select").val('').trigger("liszt:updated");
});​
```

Since the release of chosen v1.0 the trigger is now called 'chosen:updated'. Anyone using this new version needs to trigger the update using

```
$(".chosen-select").val('').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Comment: Good answer! With the latest version of Chosen, this should be "("chosen:updated")"

Comment: Great answer! But is it possible to reset and show the original placeholder again?

Comment: Still not working. I'm dynamically replacing my select via Ajax calls (jQuery load() method). Then issuing a new chosen().trigger("chosen:updated"); and does not work. The chosen search still not work on the new select.

Comment: When using this for 'multiple:true' select fields, it seems to remove the Placeholder as well. Do you know of a way to retain the Placeholder after clearing?

Comment: Ah think I found it... `$selectField.val([]).trigger('chosen:updated')` seems to do the trick

Comment: I'm here to say God bless you :)

Answer (score 55):

Since the release of chosen v1.0 the trigger is now called 'chosen:updated'. Anyone using this new version needs to trigger the update using

```
$(".chosen-select").val('').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer due to the changes. None of the other solutions I found work correctly. Thank you!

Comment: But not work! If the select is dinamically replaced with another select (jQuery load() method) with the same id/name, the search stop working on the new select. Tried to call .chosen() on the new select, to call .chosen('destroy'), to call .trigger("chosen:updated"), and combinations of these.

Answer (score 14):

You could try this:

```
$('select').chosen('destroy');  

$('select').prop("selectedIndex", -1);   
$('select').chosen();
```

Answer (score 11):

in order to have reset working naturally use this:

```
$("input[type='reset'], button[type='reset']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this).closest('form').get(0);
    form.reset();

    $(form).find('select').each(function(i, v) {
        $(v).trigger('chosen:updated');
    });
}
```

Comment: Using form.reset() and then triggering chosen:update is the best solution especially if you want to present the form as it was originally displayed. Setting .val('') does not return the form to the default values.

Comment: This is working. Remember to manually reset comboboxes (select) dinamically added to DOM.

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous options work for me. I had to do it like the old school, even using some native javascript, here is the code:

```
$('#dllSample option').each(function(){
     $(this)[0].selected = false;   
});
$("#dllSample").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#Your_id").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For a more hassle free approach...assuming your inputs are inside `<form>` tags:

```
<form>
    <!-- your selects go here and any other input fields -->
    <input type="reset" value="Reset"> 
</form>
```

This is what I would do:

```
$("input[type='reset'], button[type='reset']").click(function(e){
      setTimeout(function(){ $("select").trigger("chosen:updated"); }, 50);
});
```

See [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/spkdN/).

Comment: @MarcoMarsala if you look at the fiddle, it does work. How does your code differ from the fiddle?

Comment: I updated to 1.2.0 and all started working without hassles. I didn't even need the setTimeout. Probably was a bug in 1.12

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here worked for me.
Im using chosen select with the multiple attribute.
Normal submit form button didnt do the trick either.
So i just had a function do this upon click.

```
//Gets the selected values
var selected = [];
    for (var option of document.getElementById('mySelect').options) {
        if (option.selected) {
            selected.push(option.value);
        }

    }

//Resets the form
document.getElementById('form1').reset();

//Chosen values doesnt get reset, so we do this manually
//Removes the values selected by clicking on the x icon
$link = $('a.search-choice-close');
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
                $link[i].click();
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes you have to reset the select that chosen is called on.

I do this

```
jQuery.fn.chosen_reset = function(n){
  $(this).chosen('destroy');
  $(this).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
  $(this).chosen(n)
}
```

And call this function like this, with the options as an argument

```
$('select').chosen_reset({width:'369px'});
```

Answer (score -2):

In jQuery something like this should work

```
<input name="Text1" id="something" type="text">

<input type="reset" id="reset_me"/>


$("#reset_me").click(function() { 
$("#something").val("");
});
```

Comment: $j('.chzn-select').each(function () { $j(this).val("") }); does not clear the tags in the chosen

Comment: @P H if you could give an example of your code for us to help

Comment: sottenad just answered this, pls refer to his jsfiddle link above.  now my code looks like $j('.chzn-select').each(function () { $j(this).val("").trigger("liszt:updated"); });