# Jquery Chosen - destroy method is not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I have a bunch of select elements in a form that I am using the jQuery Chosen plugin. I am not able to reset the form:

I have referred this link but nothing worked for me:

[jQuery Chosen reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897760/jquery-chosen-reset)

My code is:

```
 $scope.share = function (share_data,type, doc_type) {
        // $('.userlist').chosen().destroy()
            $scope.sharedgroup = [];
            $scope.users_select = "";
            // $scope.sharetype = type;
            $scope.doc_type = doc_type; 
            $scope.shareid = share_data._id;
            console.log(share_data)
            $('#shareModal').modal('toggle');
        $scope.getclientshare(share_data);  
        // $(".userlist").val([]).trigger('chosen:updated')
        $scope.getfilterlist=function(){
         $http.post("/getuserslist", { 'users': 'list'}).then(function (response) {
            $scope.userlist = response.data
            $(".userlist").val('').trigger("chosen:updated");
            $timeout(function () {
               $(".userlist").chosen({ disable_search_threshold: 3 });
                $scope.page_loader = false;            
          });

         });  
        }
        $scope.getfilterlist();


    };
```

Is there any mistake I have done?

Comment: What do you expect `destroy` to do? *Delete* the selected elements? In that case I would expect `$('.userlist').chosen().destroy()` to work (I do not know the Chosen plugin, but that is how a jQuery-like fluent syntax ought to operate).

Comment: destroy will remove the selected one.  $('.userlist').chosen().destroy() am getting is not a function . https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(".chosen-select").val('').trigger("chosen:updated");

Please try this, it will set a default value in your dropdown.

Comment: what is your jquery chosen version?

Comment: $(".chzn-select").val('').trigger("liszt:updated"); try this

Comment: v1.8.7 @shubham

Comment: But its hiding after 1 sec

Comment: what is hiding default value or drop-down?

Comment: for example am selecting a value.. without saving am closing the modal.. If am again opening it removed perfectly..But after 1 second

Comment: you are using any kind of timer for reset its value.

Comment: $(".userlist").val('').trigger("chosen:updated");
            $timeout(function () {
               $(".userlist").chosen({ disable_search_threshold: 3 });
                $scope.page_loader = false;            
          });

Comment: Actually, I don't know why is it taking 1 sec but you can try to put your this line $(".userlist").val('').trigger("chosen:updated"); inside $timeout function , may be it work for you or adding after this function.

Comment: Please let me know, Are you using jquery for opening your modal popup or directly click on any tag?

Comment: clicking on share button..After that am opening modal inside function... See my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178418/discussion-between-shubham-chhapre-and-vishnu).

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".userlist").html('').chosen();
```

Comment: Thank your for your response. But its completely make empty the dropdown.. Instead of removing the selected one

Comment: please try ```$(".userlist").val('').chosen();```

Comment: another try ```$(".chzn-select").val('').trigger("change");``` or  ```$(".chzn-select").val('').trigger("update");```

Answer (score 0):

see code below

```
 $(".chzn-select").chosen();
$('a').click(function(){
    $(".chzn-select").val('').trigger("liszt:updated");
});​
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.