# How do I reset chosen-jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using jquery 3.3.1 slim min and chosen 1.8.7

inside a form I have a select multiple and a reset button:

```
<form>
  <select id="users" name="users" tabindex="2" class="form-control chosen-select" multiple>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
  </select>

  <button type="button">
    Clear
  </button>

</form>
```

I do the initialization of the chosen:

```
$("#users")
  .chosen({
    no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
  })
  .change(function(event) {

    if (event.target == this) {

      $users = $(this).val()
    }
  })
```

and when i try to reset the chosen, it doesn't update the html interface:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $("#users").val([]).trigger('chosen:updated')
})
```

What am I forgetting?

with that, I expected that it would update the interface, however it resets the value but does not update the interface html

```
$("#users").val([]).trigger('chosen:updated')
```

I also tried without success

```
$("#users").val('').trigger('chosen:updated')
```

Edit

before:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5sbc.png)

Add options
[Add options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzp7h.png)

Console
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKyxX.png)

options were not removed, however the value was reset
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWwJm.png)

Comment: have you tried `.val('')`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reset a form with jQuery chosen plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897760/how-can-i-reset-a-form-with-jquery-chosen-plugin)

Comment: @Pete, yes, i tried `.val(' ')`, but doesnt work. I saw this question too, but it didn't work.

Comment: you have a space between your quotes, unless you have a value that is a space, it won't set the value

Comment: sorry, in the code I didn't add the space.

Comment: works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/of2w7L3s/

Comment: it also worked for me, but in the application they reset the value and do not update the interface, I really don't see why `$("#users").val('').trigger('chosen:updated')` doesn't work. it's like `$("#users").val('')` works, but `.trigger('chosen:updated')` does not update the event

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code works. Maybe you are missing importing the CSS library so that's makes confusion:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css

```js
$("#users")
  .chosen({
    no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
  })
  .change(function(event) {

    if (event.target == this) {

      $users = $(this).val()
    }
  });

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $("#users").val('').trigger('chosen:updated')
});

$('a').click(()=>{
  console.log($('#users').val());
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <select id="users" name="users" tabindex="2" class="form-control chosen-select" multiple>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>

  <button type="button">
    Clear
  </button>
  <a href="#">Check Value</a>

</form>
```

Comment: I have `<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="assets/css/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` at the top of the page, I made sure that the files are the same as the cdnjs

Comment: I just edit the answer. Please make sure your code is similar

Comment: thank you for your attention. After clicking on the clear button, I check the value and it is null, but there are still the options that I selected on the screen, the elements have not been removed. Is there any more information I can give you?

Comment: Oh, I see, you want an option which not selected to disappear?

Comment: No, I just want to reset the select and have the selected options clear

Comment: Have you checked your console (inspect element)? Is there any error appearing?

Comment: I checked, there are no errors. I used it to do tests and check the values ​​of the array, the value actually resets to `[]`, however it doesn't update the element

Comment: Maybe you can include screenshot of the problem for better understanding.

Comment: added images to question